# How PEAR:Mail can save a copy of email in sent items?

Tags: php, email, smtp, imap, pear

Is that possible to save our emails when we use PEAR:Mail and send them trough SMTP server?

ex. when an email is sent with IPhone, we can see a copy of that email in Sent folder on our web mail access

I'm looking for a solution base on PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iphone (and every other mail client) does it the following way:

1. send the mail via smtp
2. store the mail via IMAP in the "Sent" IMAP folder

It's basically sending the mail 2 times to the server, once with SMTP to get it out to the world, and another time to store it in your mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

sending a mail will not automatically create  a copy of it in the 'sent' folder. Use imap_ append(). [imap_append()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php)